# how to disable Net::SSH::Expect timeout time

Tags: perl

My master scripts executes on gateway server. It invokes another script and executes it on a remote server, however there is no definite run time for the remote script. So i would like to disable the timeout..

Ok let me explain.

```
sub rollout
{
(my $path, my $address)=@_;
my $errorStatus = 0;
print "Rollout process being initiated on netsim\n";
#Creating SSH object
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect-> new (
host => "netsim",
user => 'root',
raw_pty => 1
);
#Starting SSH process
$ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";
#Start the interactive session
$ssh->exec("/tmp/rollout.pl $path $address", 30);


return $errorStatus;
}
```

When this part of the code gets executed, the rollout.pl script is invoked, however after a second the process gets killed on the remote server

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Expect allows you to just not give a timeout. And then it should wait forever. I suppose you did execute the command without giving a timeout, so what happened then?

Comment: Hi, Even i was under the same impression. However looks like there is a 1s timeout by default.

Comment: There is a timeout default of 1 second, but that is only for read operations. See my answer below. And you even could change that to 99999 or whatever. But be careful with that ^^

Comment: When i set the timeout to a greater value, the script would not get back the control of execution until such time. I cannot do this

Comment: `use `[Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)`;`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly what is going wrong let me do a wild guess at an answer. Should i missinterpret your question, i will edit this later:

The default and enforced timeout of Net::SSH::Expect is only a timeout for read operations. It does not mean, that a started script will be killed when its time has run out, it just means that the last reading operation no longer waits for it saying stuff.

You can start your remote script, for example with a timeout of 1 second and the exec call may return after one second. The string returned by `exec` will then only contain the first second of output by the remote script. But the remote script may continue to run, you just need to start a new reading operation (there are several to your choice) to capture future output. The remote script, if everything works as expected, should continue to run until it is finished or you close your ssh connection.

That means, it will be killed if you just exec, wait for that to return and then close your connection. One way to go would be to have the remote script print something when it is finished ("done" comes to mind) and wait for that string with a `waitfor` with very high timeout and only close the connection when `waitfor` has returned TRUE. Or, well, if the timeout was reasonably long, also when it returns FALSE. If you want to monitor for your script crashing, i would suggest using pgrep or ps on the remote machine. Or make sure your remote script says something when dieing, for example using `eval{} or die "done"`.

edit:

One thing to remember is, that this `exec` is in fact not something like `system`. It basically sends the command to the remote shell and hits enter. At least that is how you might visualize what is happening. But then, to appear more like `system` it waits for the default timeout of 1 second for any output and stores that in its own return value. Sadly it is a rather dumb reading operation as it just sits there and listens, so it is not a good idea to give it a high timeout or actually use it to interact with the script.

I would suggest to uses `exec` with a timeout of 0 and then use `waitfor` with a very high timeout to wait for whatever pattern your remote script puts as output once finished. And only then close your connection.

edit 2:

Just replace your exec with something like:

```
$ssh->exec("/tmp/rollout.pl $path $address", 0);
my $didItReturn = $ssh->waitfor("done", 300);
```

And make sure rollout.pl prints "done" when it is finished. And not before. Now this will start the script and then wait for up to 5 minutes for the "done". If a "done" showed up, $didItReturn will be true, if it timed out, it will be false. It will not wait for 5 minutes if it sees a "done" (as opposed to giving a timeout to `exec`).

edit 3:

If you want no timeout at all:

```
$ssh->exec("/tmp/rollout.pl $path $address", 0);
my $didItReturn = 0;
while ($didItReturn = 0)
{
    $didItReturn = $ssh->waitfor("done", 300);
}
```

Comment: Ok let me explain.                                          $ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";
#Start the interactive session
$ssh->exec("/tmp/rollout.pl $path $address");
When this part of the code gets executed, the rollout.pl script is invoked, however after a second the process gets killed on the remote server

Comment: Well, after that `exec`, what happens next? Do you close the connection? Destroy the `expect` object? The one second you wait is the timeout on the `exec` (which also is a read operation by the way) but the script may well be still running after that has returned. `exec` just stops waiting on its output. And thus, you need to make sure somehow that the script has finished before you close the connection (and with that the shell your remote script is run in and with that the remote script).

Comment: The confusion here is exec(scrip.pl) should continue execution on remote server and perform all operations, however it does not happen. I don't perform any activity as of now after exec command

Comment: The confusion here is that `exec` will not do that. `exec` is not like the normal `system` we all know and love. Basically, it just types the command into the remote shell, hits enter, stores whatever is written to the remote shell (presumably as answer to the command) within the next timeout (default=1) seconds into a string and returns that string. It does not retain of the script it started or whatever. The script still runs, even when `exec` returns. It is only killed because you close the connection afterwards. You need to wait for the script finishing by yourself.

Comment: I am updating the code in my question above. As you see there is no kill from my end

Comment: The sub ends right after the `exec`. So when it returns, the scope ends and the locally scoped `$ssh` object gets deleted. Its destructor is called and that of course closes the connection. Otherwise you would have a lot of connections still open, now that you probably tried the script a few times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42872/discussion-between-jigar-and-devadder)